# Running a .bat file in python that requires a user input

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to get an output from a `.bat` file in a python script, code works fine if I hard code a variable value in `.bat` file, but I want that value to be dynamic. 
 This is code I am using to execute the external file.

```
command = 'C:/this/this.bat'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True,
shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

text = p.stdout.read()
retcode = p.wait()
```

file `this.bat` requires a user input but I am not sure how to provide it inside python script, e.g. from a variable. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with something similar.  The way I solved it was to prompt the user for values in python.  Then using subprocess pass those values into the .bat file.

```
command = [shutil.which('C:/this/this.bat') ,sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5]]
subprocess.Popen(command).wait()
```

This assumes you can change the .bat file to take parameters instead of prompts.

Comment: Answers this, Thank you.